# React + Streamlit. Uncaught Runtime error: ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, streamlit

im trying to import a react component inside a streamlit app. Im trying to import Monaco editor through react into streamlit. i successfully added, but the issue is whenever i try to change the size of the browser, it showing error something like ResizeObserver loop error.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {ComponentProps, Streamlit, withStreamlitConnection} from "streamlit-component-lib";
import {ReactElement} from "react";
import {Editor} from "@monaco-editor/react";

function TestField({args}: ComponentProps): ReactElement {
    // const {title} = args


    const initialValues = {
        codeContent: '',
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        Streamlit.setFrameHeight(600)
    })

    const onSubmit = (values: any, {setSubmitting}: any) =>{
        setSubmitting(false)
        Streamlit.setComponentValue(values)
    }

    const onReset = () =>{
        Streamlit.setComponentValue({})
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Editor
                height="100vh"
                width="100%"
                theme="vs-dark"
                defaultLanguage="python"
                options={{
                    fontSize: 17
                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default withStreamlitConnection(TestField);
```

This is the actual code im using. i used template from the github repo. i just created a component and nothing changed from the repo. so what is the error and how can i solve it?

im trying to solve the error that raise when browser size is changed. I tried with bypass this error, but nothing works